# Why is navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPostion being blocked?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I didn't change my code at all. It was working perfectly for days then all of a sudden the success callback function for navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition stopped running.

My code is:

```
if(navigator.geolocation){
   alert("you have geolocation");
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPostion(function(pos){
     alert(pos.coords.longitude);
   });
}
```

The developer console gives me this error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://s.codepen.io" from accessing a frame with origin "http://codepen.io". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

I'm using codepen as my editor and I think the problem is on their end because this is the code I have been using for days and it's been working just fine.

Comment: Each user can set which sites they will allow geolocation for. When your phone/device/computer first accesses a site which requests geolocation, you will be prompted for permission. If you deny the permission, then no geolocation information will be returned.

Comment: It doesn't request permission though... it just doesn't run

Comment: Well, since I don't know anything about Codepen, and it seems Duncan knows what he's talking about, I guess that's the situation.

Comment: it's a browser restriction related to cross domain security. Could be related to a recent upgrade in your browser, or a change of iframe domain at codepen.

Answer (score 2):

As the console error states, the problem is that you are trying to make requests across 2 different domains (note the subdomain in `http://s.codepen.io`).

While it's not quite true that 'the problem is on their end' (this isn't a problem for codepen), it is true that there is nothing you can do to work around this. You are completely at the mercy of the codepen infrastructure, and they can do with it what they like.

Ultimately, you shouldn't be using codepen as a development environment for things like this. There are many free editors available that will allow you to develop and test this locally.